# How to add initial padding to progress bar by java code

Tags: android, padding, android-progressbar, shapedrawable

I want to add initial padding to progress bar, but that would be dynamic, as i am retrieving that value for initial padding from local database.

I have set progress bar's background with layer-list xml file.
 `

```
    <corners android:radius="7dip" />

    <gradient  
            android:startColor="@color/background_start"  
            android:centerColor="@color/background_center"  
            android:centerY="0.75"  
            android:endColor="@color/background_end"  
            android:angle="270"  />  
     <stroke 
            android:color="@color/stroke"
            android:width="0.5dip"/> 
</shape>
```

> ```
>         <corners android:radius="7dip" />
>         <gradient  
>                 android:startColor="@color/secondory_progress_start"  
>                 android:centerColor="@color/secondory_progress_center"  
>                 android:centerY="0.75"  
>                 android:endColor="@color/secondory_progress_end"  
>                 android:angle="270"  />
>            <stroke 
>             android:color="@color/stroke"
>             android:width="0.5dip"/>  
>     </shape> 
>  </clip>
> ```

```
        <corners  
            android:radius="7dip" /> 

         <padding android:left="360dip" 
             android:right="50dip"/>
        <gradient  
                android:startColor="@color/default_progress_start"  
                android:centerColor="@color/default_progress_center"
                android:centerY="0.75"  
                android:endColor="@color/default_progress_end"  
                android:angle="270"  
        />  
         <stroke 
            android:color="@color/stroke"
            android:width="0.5dip"/> 
    </shape> 
   </clip>
```

And in java code, i am referencing xml file, like this:

`layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable)progressBar.getProgressDrawable();`

and retrieving simple progress child like this:
`Drawable drawable = layerDrawable.getDrawable(layerDrawable.getId(2));`  as it is on 2nd level of xml file.

And i set max value and progress value to progress bar. Now i want to add some left padding to progressbar's progress value. which i tried like this using setBounds method:

`Rect rect = new Rect();

rect = drawable.getBounds();

rect.left = drawable.getBounds().left + getPaddingForFirstPeriod() + 300;
rect.right = rect.left + (int) 50;
drawable.setBounds(rect);`

But it's not taking any effect on progressbar's primary progress value, and apart from this there is no padding method available for it.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Does old kind `View.setPadding(l,t,r,b)` not help any more?

Comment: it isn't Simple view, its a drawable/clipdrawable :(

Comment: Unfortunately i am trying to set Bounds also, drawable.setBounds(100, 0, 300, 0); though its not taking any effect.

Comment: What class does `progressBar` object instantiate?